# iPhone: How to sync large library of MP3 + flac files from Win10 laptop

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore, music, mp3

I am a longtime android user looking to migrate to iphone (to get better privacy).

I think I have everything solved except for one thing: My music library.

I am old school, in that I have a large (120+GB, constantly growing) library of music files. This is primarily maintained on my Win10 laptop (and backed up to the cloud).

With Android, I just plug the phone into a usb port, and do a file copy from the laptop to the phone.

On the phone, I use BlackPlayerEX to manage playlists and be the playback app.

On iPhone 11/12, how do I:

1. Sync my music library to the phone
2. Have a blackplayer equivalent on iphone (VLC for iPhone?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this I suggest the simplest one .

First you need to download iMazing app on your windows .

[iMazing PC Download](https://imazing.com/download/windows)

[iMazing MacOS Download](https://imazing.com/download/macos)

1. Launch iMazing and connect your device to your Mac or PC.
2. Select your device in the sidebar, then select "Music".
3. Click "Import from Folder", and select the music you want to import.
4. Transfer your Music.